# corresponding comparison of vectors within a list in R

Tags: r, for-loop, mapply

I have a list of 4 logical vectors (mylist):

```
list(a = c(NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, 
NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, 
FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, 
NA, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, 
FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, 
FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, 
TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE, 
NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, 
NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, 
NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, 
NA, NA), b = c(NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, 
NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, 
FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, 
NA, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, 
TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, 
FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, FALSE, 
NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, 
NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, 
NA, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, 
NA, NA), c = c(NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, 
TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, 
TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, 
NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, 
NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, 
TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, 
NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, 
NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, 
NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, 
NA), d = c(NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, 
NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, 
FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, 
NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, NA, TRUE, FALSE, NA, 
FALSE, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
TRUE, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, 
FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, FALSE, FALSE, 
NA, FALSE, NA, NA, FALSE, NA, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
NA, TRUE, NA, NA))
```

I want a function that would return a logical vector with TRUE values when ANY corresponding value from the original vectors is TRUE (output_vector).
When any of the following: (mylist[[1]][[i]], mylist[[2]][[i]], mylist[[3]][[i]], mylist[[4]][[i]]) is TRUE, output_vector[i] should be TRUE.

I came up with two solutions, one with nested for loops, the other with mapply:

#Nested for loops:

```
my_function<-function(){
        my_vector<-logical(length(mylist[[1]]))
        for (i in 1:length(mylist[[1]])){
                for (j in 1:length(mylist)){
                        my_vector[i]<-any(mylist[[j]][[i]]==T)
                }
        }
my_vector
}

my_function()
```

## mapply:

```
mapply(any, mylist[[1]], mylist[[2]], mylist[[3]], mylist[[4]])
```

I am surprised because:
1-) the #mapply and #nested for loops methods yielded different results

Maybe there is something wrong with the nested for loops method? mapply looks much cleaner and wielded results in line with my expectations, though.

bonus question: is there a way to use some sort of do.call() in the mapply method so that I do not have to write out every argument to any()?

Comment: With `mapply` you are doing a corresponding comparison.  Do you want a comparison as in the `for` loop

Comment: Hi @akrun , I want a corresponding comparison. Did I get it wrong in the for loop?

Comment: I think the answer to the bonus question is something like this:
do.call(mapply, c(any, mylist))

Comment: your corresponding comparison is `unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = any, mylist)))` instead of specifying each element

Comment: Ok thank you @akrun. I see your method yield exactly the same result as my mapply method. Is there any bad practice in my way? Not so sure why I need to call unlist() and map()

Comment: With `mapply`, the argument is `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` by default, so it may coerce to a matrix or remain as a `list` and it depends while `Map`, we can be sure that it is always returning a `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need an elementwise comparison, use `Reduce`

```
out1 <- Reduce(`|`, mylist)
```

which is similar to the `do.call` method with `Map` and `any`

```
out2 <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = any, mylist)))
all.equal(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In the nested `for` loop

```
mylist[[j]][[i]]
```

is a single element in the `list` which is getting wrapped with `any`.  Therefore, the `my_vector` which was initialized as the `length` of the first `vector` element of 'mylist' is getting recycled and it will return the output of the last `list` element

If we make a small change in the `function`  `for` loop, it would give the same output i.e. the key is to check whether the elements in 'my_vector' at the same position along with the element indexed  from 'mylist' have `any` TRUE values instead of just checking a single element and overwriting it to `my_vector`

```
 my_function<-function(){
         my_vector <- logical(length(mylist[[1]]))
         for (i in 1:length(mylist[[1]])){
                 for (j in 1:length(mylist)){
                         my_vector[i] <- any(c(my_vector[i], mylist[[j]][[i]]))
                 }
         }
       my_vector
 }

 out3 <- my_function()
identical(out1, out3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option that may apply to your question

```
colSums(do.call(rbind,mylist))>1
```

where the number of `TRUE`s in columns is counted. If there exists a `NA`, then a `NA` is returned.